# Is two-ways fixed effect model better than one-way fixed effect model?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

Is two-ways fixed effect better than one-way fixed effect?

How should we decide between one-way FE and two-way FE?

Is there any test for this purpose?

Comment: Better in what sense? In what context? Without those, your query is as impossible to answer as the question about whether a raincoat and an umbrella are better than just one of them.

Comment: @dimitriy How should we decide between one-way FE and two-way FE as our final model? suppose you have done these two model for your data, then how do you choose the final model as your result?

Comment: I use theory and domain knowledge to pick the main specification. If you have a short panel, with big N and small T, I would eliminate the person fixed effect by demeaning and put in time dummies (dropping one). Then test the null that all time dummies are jointly zero. If you have something more exotic, then something more unusual will be needed.